# Which is lighter/quicker: LXDM or LightDM?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, lxdm

I am using lubuntu and I am just wondering whether it would be worth switching from the default LXDM to LightDM.  Are there any speed advantages of LightDM over LXDM?  (An answer with more than one work is preferred.)

Comment: Forget about it, you need to do a lot of manual work to add Lubuntu profiles to LightDM. I should know - I tried it. It did not even load.

Comment: @Oxwivi Can you give more information about your system? I had a regular Ubuntu (not Lubuntu) 11.10 system with LightDM, and I installed `lubuntu-desktop` without switching to LXDM, and the Lubuntu profiles were automatically added to the LightDM session selection menu and they work fine.

Comment: @EliahKagan I installed minimal Ubuntu with LightDM instead of LXDM. Maybe LightDM captures profiles from other DMs? I don't know.

Comment: @Oxwivi Was this a minimal Oneiric (11.10) system?

Comment: @EliahKagan Yes.

Answer (score 7):

Lightdm depens upon gnome-settings-daemon, so requirements for lightdm ends up in two daemons. Lxde is only one daemon. It seems lxdm is lighter than lightdm in that respect.